# Undetected Chromedriver Crashing Unexpectedly

Tags: python, selenium, crash, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a program that logs into google by using undetected-chromedriver. I'm running this on Replit but it crashes directly after opening google.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://mail.google.com')
```

This is the error that it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/runner/Undetected-Chromedriver/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 401, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "/home/runner/Undetected-Chromedriver/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/runner/Undetected-Chromedriver/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/runner/Undetected-Chromedriver/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/runner/Undetected-Chromedriver/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/runner/.local/share/undetected_chromedriver/36af9f1b1cb26672_chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

[screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLaC4.png)

Is there a fix to this problem or another method that can get me logged into Google?

Comment: I would check major versions first.  Chromedriver major version should match Chrome's major version. (right now you're probably at v101 for Chrome so Chromedriver should match or you should set environment variable to skip version check.)

Comment: I don't know how to check for Chromedriver versions on Replit. I tried running this on Pycharm but even with version 101 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=101.0.4951.41/) I'm still getting an unsupported error.

Answer (score 1):

i am also facing same issue. try this its work for me

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    
def browser():
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
         driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
         driver.get('https://mail.google.com')
```

Comment: fixed  months ago by updating chromium version